# PHP - traversing through nested arrays

Tags: php

How would i go about looping through $data and printing the caller id???

```
$data = <some json file>

Array ( 
      [0] => Array( 
                  [result] =>   Array( 
                                     [0] => Array(  
                                                 [caller_id] => John Smith
                                                 )
                                     [1] => Array(  
                                                 [caller_id] => Jane Doe
                                                 )
                                     )
                 )
     [1] => Array( 
                  [status] => 200 
                  [headers] => Array ( 
                                     [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
                                     [response_code] => 200 
                                     [Connection] => close 
                                     ) 
                  )
 )
```

It gets rather confusing when going deeper and deeper into JSON/nested arrays

Thanks

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, and it's not possible to determine the best way  based on the example shown. With a nested structure like this, you need to examine the structure and decide which levels should be iterated and which levels should be dereferenced.

Comment: What do you mean dereferenced?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misspoke. I was just referring to accessing array values by key, like `$return[0]` or `$value['number']`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have a similar structure to mine. I have figured it out...

```
foreach($return[0] as $items) {
    foreach($items as $value) {
        echo $value['number'];
    }
}
```

Used return[0] as this is the only element in the top array we want to pay attention to, holds the results.